# youtube: send video to channel use API

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

I have a YouTube channel. I want add new feature to my site:

1. user auth using their google account
2. user create own video podcast (use this [widget](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget)) and upload it into their youtube account
3. after that I move users video into my channel use YouTube API.

Is it possible to allow some users to upload videos of their accounts on my channel?
Maybe users can do it is through Google Plus?

P.S. I read some article where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all of this with YouTube Direct Lite.

[YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/) allows you to solicit videos from your users and then moderate those submissions into standard YouTube playlists for display.

There is also an [Android app](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android), if you want mobile experience too.